# Boolean indexing using loc resulting in an error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, boolean

I have two different dataframes of the same stock, but one dataframe has more data and different prices.
I want to compare one of the columns, to see where they differ.
(Below are a smaller version of the dataframes)

`df`

```
Date          Open    Close
2007-03-22    3.65      1.0
2007-03-23    3.87      1.0
2007-03-26    3.83      1.0
2007-03-27    3.61      1.0
2007-03-28    4.65      1.0
```

`df2`

```
Date          Open   Close
2007-03-22    3.15    1.0
2007-03-23    3.87    0.0
2007-03-26    3.33    0.0
2007-03-27    3.61    0.0
2007-03-28    4.65    0.0
```

Since one of of the dataframe has more dates, I'm trying to slice it using loc and then use boolean indexing to find out where they differ.

I tried some like this

```
df.Open[df.loc['2010-01-04':, 'Open'] != df2.loc['2010-01-04':, 'Open']]
```

I only want to compare the "Open" columns of both dataframes, and only at a slice of dates. I want the output, to be just the df.Open column (and index) at where they differ in their respective 'Open' columns.

but I'm getting the error,

`pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use Boolean indexing, the object to be subsetted must have the same length as the Boolean Series, try the following:

```
df.Open.loc['2010-01-04':][df.loc['2010-01-04':, 'Open'] != df2.loc['2010-01-04':, 'Open']]
```

The error can be reproduced with this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,4]})    
df.A[df.loc[2:, 'A'] == df.loc[2:, 'A']]
```

> IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided

But this works fine:

```
df.A.loc[2:][df.loc[2:, 'A'] == df.loc[2:, 'A']]

#2    3
#3    4
#Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Very interesting. I didn't know about this rule.  Thank you.